# Select specific range of elements from a python dictionary based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-munging

I have the following dictionary:

```
ip_dict = 
{
    "doc_1" : {
                "img_1" : ("FP","some long text"),
                "img_2" : ("LP", "another long text"),
                "img_3" : ("Others", "long text"),
                "img_4" : ("Others", "some loong text"),
                "img_5" : ("FP", "one more text"),
                "img_6" : ("FP", "another one"),
                "img_7" : ("LP", "ANOTHER ONE"),
                "img_8" : ("Others", "some text"),
                "img_9" : ("Others", "some moretext"),
                "img_10" : ("FP", "more text"),
                "img_11" : ("Others", "whatever"),
                "img_12" : ("Others", "more whatever"),
                "img_13" : ("LP", "SoMe TeXt"),
                "img_14" : ("Others", "some moretext"),
                "img_15" : ("FP", "whatever"),
                "img_16" : ("Others", "whatever"),
                "img_17" : ("LP", "whateverrr")
            },

    "doc_2" : {
                "img_1" : ("FP", "text"),
                "img_2" : ("FP", "more text"),
                "img_3" : ("LP", "more more text"),
                "img_4" : ("Others", "some more"),
                "img_5" : ("Others", "text text"),
                "img_6" : ("FP", "more more text"),
                "img_7" : ("Others", "lot of text"),
                "img_8" : ("LP", "still more text")
            }

}
```

Here `FP` represents the first page and `LP` the last page. For all the `docs` I only want to extract the `FP` and `LP`. For the `Others`, if they lie between `FP` and `LP` only then extract them, as they represent the pages between `FP` and `LP`. If they lie outside `FP` and `LP` then ignore them. Also for `FP` which are not followed by a `LP`, treat them as a single page and extract them. So my output dictionary would look like:

```
op_dict = 
{
    "doc_1" : [
                {
                "img_1" : ("FP","some long text"),
                "img_2" : ("LP", "another long text")
                },

                {
                    "img_5" : ("FP", "one more text")
                },

                {
                    "img_6" : ("FP", "another one"),
                    "img_7" : ("LP", "ANOTHER ONE")
                },

                {
                    "img_10" : ("FP", "more text"),
                    "img_11" : ("Others", "whatever"),
                    "img_12" : ("Others", "more whatever"),
                    "img_13" : ("LP", "SoMe TeXt"),
                },

                {
                    "img_15" : ("FP", "whatever"),
                    "img_16" : ("Others", "whatever"),
                    "img_17" : ("LP", "whateverrr"),
                }
            ],


    "doc_2" : [

                {
                "img_1" : ("FP", "text")
                },

                {        
                "img_2" : ("FP", "more text"),
                "img_3" : ("LP", "more more text")
                },        

                {
                "img_6" : ("FP", "more more text"),
                "img_7" : ("Others", "lot of text"),
                "img_8" : ("LP", "still more text")
                },

            ]
}
```

As you can see, all the `FP` and `LP` have been extracted, but also those `Others` which are in between `FP` and `LP` have also been extracted and stored in a dictionary. Also those `FP` which are not followed by a `LP` have also been extracted.

**PS:**

```
ip_dict = 
{
    "doc_1" : {
                "img_1" : ("LP","some long text"),
                "img_2" : ("Others", "another long text"),
                "img_3" : ("Others", "long text"),
                "img_4" : ("FP", "long text"),
                "img_5" : ("Others", "long text"),
                "img_6" : ("LP", "long text")
            }
}

op_dict =     {
        "doc_1" : [{
                    "img_1" : ("LP","some long text")
                },
                    {
                    "img_4" : ("FP", "long text"),
                    "img_5" : ("Others", "long text"),
                    "img_6" : ("LP", "long text")
                    }
                  ]
    
              }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Dictionaries don't have order (well, at least conceptually). There is no "between" of elements in them.

Comment: @matszwecja Yes but the author is saying if `Others` appear in between `FP` and `LP` then only consider them. If not then ignore them

Comment: @shreyjain But they can't appear "between" them in an **unordered** structure.

Comment: As of Python3.6+, dictionaries do retain their insertion order (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6), though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With extended sequential logic:

```
def select_page_ranges(d: dict):

    def _del_excess_items():
        # if previous block was not closed and has excess entries
        if start and last_mark != 'FP':
            res[pk][-1] = {start_key: res[pk][-1][start_key]}

    res = {}
    for pk, v in ip_dict.items():
        res[pk] = []
        start, start_key, last_mark = None, None, ''
        for k, v in v.items():
            if v[0] == 'FP':
                _del_excess_items()
                res[pk].append({k: v})
                start = True
                start_key = k
            elif v[0] == 'LP':
                res[pk][-1].update({k: v})
                start = False
            elif start:
                res[pk][-1].update({k: v})
            last_mark = v[0]
        _del_excess_items()
    return res

print(select_page_ranges(ip_dict))
```

---

```
{'doc_1': [{'img_1': ('FP', 'some long text'),
            'img_2': ('LP', 'another long text')},
           {'img_5': ('FP', 'one more text')},
           {'img_6': ('FP', 'another one'), 'img_7': ('LP', 'ANOTHER ONE')},
           {'img_61': ('FP', 'another one'), 'img_71': ('LP', 'ANOTHER ONE')},
           {'img_62': ('FP', 'another one'), 'img_72': ('LP', 'ANOTHER ONE')},
           {'img_54': ('FP', 'one more text')},
           {'img_540': ('FP', 'one more text')},
           {'img_541': ('FP', 'one more text')},
           {'img_13': ('FP', 'more text'),
            'img_14': ('Others', 'whatever'),
            'img_140': ('Others', 'whatever'),
            'img_141': ('Others', 'whatever'),
            'img_142': ('Others', 'whatever'),
            'img_15': ('Others', 'more whatever'),
            'img_16': ('LP', 'SoMe TeXt')},
           {'img_18': ('FP', 'whatever'),
            'img_19': ('Others', 'whatever'),
            'img_20': ('LP', 'whateverrr')}],
 'doc_2': [{'img_1': ('FP', 'text')},
           {'img_2': ('FP', 'more text'), 'img_3': ('LP', 'more more text')},
           {'img_6': ('FP', 'more more text'),
            'img_7': ('Others', 'lot of text'),
            'img_8': ('LP', 'still more text')},
           {'img_69': ('FP', 'more more text')}]}
```

Comment: Nice. Upvote +1 . Can you explain what you mean by sequential logic and perhaps how the update methods work here? I don't quite see it yet 

Comment: @JohnCollins, "sequential logic" - just because all the entries are processed sequentially once (without possible additional traversals). https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update takes the last dict in the current sublist and updates it with an entry (other dict)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Your solution does not work when we have consecutive `FP`. I have added the sample example in my question along with the expected output

Comment: @spectre *when we have consecutive FP* - you should have said "when we have more than **2** consecutive FP"

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry about that. Must have escaped my attention!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thank you brother. But I forgot to add one more case where except for one `FP` all are `Others`. Can you please cover that case too? Really sorry but this came up while I was testing your approach! I'll mark your answer as the correct answer as the other answers cannot handle this case. I have added the scenario in `PS2:` in my question. Again I am really sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest +1 and marked as answer. Thanks a lot brother!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry to bother you once again brother...your code is working fine except for when there is only a `LP` in the dictionary. Y=In this case, I get an error `List index out of range`. For the past 2 days I am trying to solve it but no solution. Can you kindly look at the `PS` case scenario in my question if it's not too much trouble. i'd really appreciate your time. Thanks again!

Comment: @spectre, you can not change conditions/requirements every time, feel free to create a new question with current state and a new requirement

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I don't mind creating a new question but then it would be the same as the current question and hence would get closed. That is why I asked you.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```py
op_dict = {}
first_page = None
for doc, imgs in ip_dict.items():
    op_dict[doc] = []
    for k, v in imgs.items():
        if v[0] == "FP":
            if first_page:
                if len(new.keys()) == 1:
                    op_dict[doc].append(new)
                else:
                    op_dict[doc].append(
                        {list(new.keys())[0]: list(new.values())[0]}
                    )
                new = {}
            else:
                new = {k: v}
                first_page = True
                continue
        if first_page:
            new[k] = v
            if v[0] == "LP":
                op_dict[doc].append(new)
                first_page = False
    if first_page:
        op_dict[doc].append({k: v})
```

which gives:

```
{'doc_1': [{'img_1': ('FP', 'some long text'),
   'img_2': ('LP', 'another long text')},
  {'img_5': ('FP', 'one more text')},
  {'img_6': ('FP', 'another one'), 'img_7': ('LP', 'ANOTHER ONE')},
  {'img_61': ('FP', 'another one'), 'img_71': ('LP', 'ANOTHER ONE')},
  {'img_62': ('FP', 'another one'), 'img_72': ('LP', 'ANOTHER ONE')},
  {'img_54': ('FP', 'one more text')},
  {'img_540': ('FP', 'one more text')},
  {'img_541': ('FP', 'one more text')},
  {'img_13': ('FP', 'more text'),
   'img_14': ('Others', 'whatever'),
   'img_140': ('Others', 'whatever'),
   'img_141': ('Others', 'whatever'),
   'img_142': ('Others', 'whatever'),
   'img_15': ('Others', 'more whatever'),
   'img_16': ('LP', 'SoMe TeXt')},
  {'img_18': ('FP', 'whatever'),
   'img_19': ('Others', 'whatever'),
   'img_20': ('LP', 'whateverrr')}],
 'doc_2': [{'img_1': ('FP', 'text')},
  {'img_2': ('FP', 'more text'), 'img_3': ('LP', 'more more text')},
  {'img_6': ('FP', 'more more text'),
   'img_7': ('Others', 'lot of text'),
   'img_8': ('LP', 'still more text')},
  {'img_69': ('FP', 'more more text')}]}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work when the last element is `FP`. Also when a `FP` is followed by `Others` and then `FP` then your solution groups these 3 together which is not the desired result. I have added the sample example in the question.

Comment: I have added the example as well the expected output in the question

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution which is pretty long:

```
for doc in ip_dict:
    print('\n', doc, '\n')

    ignore = True

    for img in ip_dict[doc]:
    
        TYPE = ip_dict[doc][img][0] # FP or LP
        TEXT = ip_dict[doc][img][1] # The text
    
        if TYPE == 'FP':
            ignore = False
    
        if ignore == False:
            print(img,' :\t', TYPE, '/', TEXT)
        
        if TYPE == 'LP':
            ignore = True
```

result:

```
doc_1 

img_1  :     FP / some long text
img_2  :     LP / another long text
img_5  :     FP / one more text
img_6  :     FP / another one
img_7  :     LP / ANOTHER ONE
img_10  :    FP / more text
img_11  :    Others / whatever
img_12  :    Others / more whatever
img_13  :    LP / SoMe TeXt
img_15  :    FP / whatever
img_16  :    Others / whatever
img_17  :    LP / whateverrr

doc_2 

img_1  :     FP / text
img_2  :     FP / more text
img_3  :     LP / more more text
img_6  :     FP / more more text
img_7  :     Others / lot of text
img_8  :     LP / still more text
```

Comment: This does not give the output in the form of a dictionary which is what the user asked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. This is a classic usage of flag method, but as of the comment that it will only work if you make the input into the dictionary in order. as o now, it is giving the desired output

```
def process(ip_dict):
    op_dict=dict()
    for key,value in ip_dict.items():
        op_list=[]
        fp_counter=0
        lp_counter=0
        op_dup=dict()
        for key1,value1 in value.items():
            if value1[0] == "FP" and fp_counter==1:
                fp_counter=1
                if len(op_dup) != 0:
                    op_list.append(op_dup)
                op_dup=dict()
                op_dup[key1]=value1
                continue
            
            if value1[0] == "FP" and fp_counter==0:
                fp_counter=1
                
               
            if value1[0] == "LP" and lp_counter==1:
                lp_counter=1
                if len(op_dup) != 0:
                    op_list.append(op_dup)
                op_dup=dict()
                op_dup[key1]=value1
                continue
            
            if value1[0] == "LP" and lp_counter==0:
                lp_counter=1
                
            if(lp_counter==0 and fp_counter == 1):
                op_dup[key1]=value1
                
            if(lp_counter == 1 and fp_counter == 1 and value1[0] == "LP"):
                op_dup[key1]=value1
                
            if(lp_counter == 1 and fp_counter == 1 and value1[0] != "LP"):
                if len(op_dup) != 0:
                    op_list.append(op_dup)
                op_dup=dict()
                lp_counter=0
                fp_counter=0
        if(len(op_dup) != 0):
            op_list.append(op_dup)
        op_dict[key]=op_list
    return op_dict

print(process(ip_dict))
```